# C, Cannot retrieve variable value through dereferencing, unknown segmentation fault

Tags: c, pointers, methods, dereference

If I do the operation on the pointer within the method, it works. But when used as a argument in another method the same operation fails. There's clearly something I'm missing. My guess is for some reason foobar can't "see" the variables *ptr is pointing to.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned short b =15;
    unsigned short *ptr = &b;

    //If I do it in main it works
    unsigned short c = 10 & (*ptr);

    //If I send it to foobar, it segfaults
    foobar(*ptr);
}

void foobar(unsigned short *ptr){
    unsigned short c = 10 & (*ptr);
}
```

How do I get my variable over to the foobar, if I foobar(unsigned short b) it does not compile (through trial and error I've found you can only use basic types as arguments).

If anyone could 'point' me to an explanation I would be grateful. I've read several C tutorials, but I can't find a specific reason why this happens, or how to solve it.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the "segmentation fault?"

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
 foobar(*ptr);
```

you are sending the **dereferenced pointer** to the function. So you are passing an unsigned short argument instead of **pointer** to unsigned short. The function expects a pointer so you should pass a pointer. What you need is

```
 foobar(ptr);
```

and your code will compile

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `ptr` to `foobar`, not `*ptr`.

Comment: Have spent hours on this trying various different combinations. Its almost depressing that it is this trivial. Many thanks, to everyone who posted.

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you are passing not the address of b stored in ptr, but the value of b.
In other words, the foobar is getting ptr = 10, which is not a valid address. When you dereference it inside (`unsigned short c = 10 & (*ptr);`), you are getting a segfault.

Looks like you simply need to pass the pointer to the foobar function, which could be achieved in the following way `foobar(ptr);`.

Answer (score 0):

`foobar` expects a *pointer* to an `unsigned short`. But you pass an `unsigned short` when you de-reference `ptr` in the argument list: `foobar(*ptr);`, so `foobar` gets `10` as an address. Using `10` as an address - it's de-referenced in the single line that is the body of `foobar` - causes the segfault.

Call the function, passing your pointer, like so: `foobar(ptr);`, and you can use the value as you did in the statement in `main`.